# "Be like night" vs "Be like the night"

Tags: word-usage, articles, poetry

I'm sorry if this question is somewhat basic. I have a sentence here that goes like this:

> Be **like night**, in covering others’ mistakes
>   And like the earth, in being humble;
>   In love and friendliness, be like the sun;
>   And during anger and rage, like a mountain;
>   Be like a river in generosity and helping others;
>   And in coping with others, like a sea.

But the "like night" part, sounds somewhat off to me. 
should I use ***the*** here as well, or this is OK as is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By dropping the article, the author is personifying 'night'. None of the other allegories used lend themselves to this.